# Update multiple mysql tables with one json in php

Tags: php, mysql, json, backend, fat-free-framework

I've got an `AngularJS` frontend and got some problems relating the data layer.

In the frontend I've got contacts.

contact `JSON` object:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "groupId": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email": "jd@gmail.com",
    "company": "Google",
    "info": "lorem ipsum dolor amet",
    "numbers": [
      {
        "typeId": 1,
        "number": "123456"
      },
      {
        "typeId": 2,
        "number": "1234567"
      },
      {
        "typeId": 3,
        "number": "8765432"
      },
      {
        "typeId": 4,
        "number": "0864235"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I get this object over an url with one http request.

When I will save it I give exactly this object back to the backend.

But how can I e.g. update a number out of the numbers table or the company out of the companies table with php?

My colleague said to me that when i update a number in the contact object, i have to call an url with `/numbers/id` .
But I just want to put back a "contact object" at `/contacts`
and let the business layer/data layer do the logic and split the object to update different tables.

In the backend he uses `php` and fat-free-framework.

Can anyone explain how to do this?

-EDIT-

And I thought the complete logic how to save the data is in the backend.
With DTO (Data Transfer Object) and DAO (Data Access Object) etc.

Comment: It would certainly be more efficient to follow your colleague's advice than to attempt updating the entire contact.

Comment: @Xstian what do you mean with format keywords?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept an object graph then you would need to parse it then make the appropriate calls to the database.

For example, presuming you have a table "numbers" that has columns "typeId" and "number" you would probably want logic in your "contact" class that does something like...

```
// convert the JSON to PHP
$request = json_decode($contact);
if(isset($request->numbers)) {
    $number = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($this->db, "number");
    // loop over your number objects
    foreach($request->numbers as $data) {
        // create a new number entry for each one
        $number->copyfrom($data);
        $number->save();
        $number->reset();
    }
}
```

Obviously how and where you do this would depend on how you have structured your code, for example `contact->post()` and `contact->put()` might be applicable places.